# Inserting Null items into a collection Mongodb (Pymongo)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, performance, pymongo

Disclaimer: I'm a newbie when it comes to mongo..

So i have this data from a text-file that i am processing into  "python dictionary" format so that it can be inserted into a collection i created using Pymongo.

raw data changed to text, apologies... can be viewed here on pastebin
[Link to raw data text](https://pastebin.com/U1J3bGX8)

And here is the formatted dictionary in python for insertion

```
[{'Poll_Name': 'ECU', 'Date': '2020-05-07', 'Sample_Size': '--', 'MoE': '--', 'Biden (D)': '46', 'Trump(R)': '43', 'Spread': 'Trump +3'}, {'Poll_Name': 'WRAL-TV', 'Date': '2020-04-23', 'Sample_Size': '580 LV', 'MoE': '5.5', 'Biden (D)': '45', 'Trump(R)': '50', 'Spread': 'Biden +5'}, {'Poll_Name': 'PPP (D)', 'Date': '2020-04-14', 'Sample_Size': '1318 RV', 'MoE': '2.7', 'Biden (D)': '47', 'Trump(R)': '48', 'Spread': 'Biden +1'}, {'Poll_Name': 'Civitas', 'Date': '2020-04-05', 'Sample_Size': '500 LV', 'MoE': '4.4', 'Biden (D)': '49', 'Trump(R)': '42', 'Spread': 'Trump +7'}]
```

I have all the dictionary data inserted into an array and the i plan to do an insertmany() with it.

Here is the code i have so far for the exporting of this data in dictionary format

```
def export_Data(filename):
export_List = [] #list that will contain the dictionary values of the data
key_List = ["Poll_Name", "Date", "Sample_Size", "MoE", "Biden (D)", "Trump(R)", "Spread"] #list of keys for each value
count = 0 
temp_List = []
with(open(filename, "r")) as infile: #opening the file of raw data
    for line in infile:
        count += 1
        temp_List.append(line.strip("\n")) #i add each line of infile to this temporary list 
        if count % len(key_List) == 0: #when 7 items are added
            temp_dict = {} #create a temporary dictionary 
            for key, line in zip(key_List, temp_List): #fill in dictionary key values..
                temp_dict[key] = line
            temp_List = [] # resetting the temporary dictionary
            export_List.append(temp_dict) #appending dictionary to final list
print(export_List)
#export the list later once i get properly formatted..
```

Now as you can see some of the entries found in both the text file and the dictionary sample are seen as "--", these are suppost to represent empty/null values.
I want to insert values like these as null and not "--" into my database so as to avoid having to do a mass update query in mongo, i feel like it might make the data cleaning/export process simpler and faster.
Is there any way i can change these values so they can be inserted as null instead of "--"
Would appreciate any solutions, I know there is probably a simple answer! but this newbie would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: can we see the code that processes the text?  Also a field being null, undefined, and non-existent are different in MongoDB.  That may be important depending on how you plan to index and query this data.

Comment: It's also a lot easier to see text if you copy paste it into the question as text.  Screenshots only really look right on the same size screen they were taken, so viewing them on mobile is a real pain.

Comment: Sorry, i changed it to text just there, hope this helps. Thanks for bearing with me. Also added some extra code on the exporting

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with null values in mongo, would appreciate any resource or explanation on how they work. Didnt even know they affect indexing and querying data

Comment: If it is not critical that they be exactly null, it might actually be simpler to make them the empty string, if that works with how you plan to query.

Comment: I see what you mean, and yes that may be a good solution, keeping it simple. But if it isint too difficult to answer, how would a null value differ from a blank  string in terms of querying data. I'm not too sure what you are getting at there.

Comment: It all depends on how you plan to query.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/#query-for-null-or-missing-fields and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#exists

Comment: Thanks, so after reading that I am definitely  going to need null values and not blank strings, any ideas how i can insert as null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly replace "--" with any value of your choice in that loop:

instead of

```
        temp_List.append(line.strip("\n"))
```

```
        temp_str = line.strip("\n")
        temp_list.append(temp_str if (temp_str != "--") else "")
```

If you would rather use `null` or `undefined` or "Not Provided" or whatever, just replace `""` with what you'd like to use.